# libxml2 with extended ASCII and UTF-8 C APIs

Tags: c, utf-8, libxml2

I wrote a C application that creates an XML file using libxml2. I opened the XML file using:

```
xmlTextWriterStartDocument(xmlFileWriter->writer, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

One of the strings that I write contains extended ASCII code:

```
xmlTextWriterWriteElement(TPCBData->writer, BAD_CAST    "DESCRIPTION", "Ã");
```

When parsing the file using `xmlParseFile` it gives me error:

```
Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
```

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is backward compatible with basic ASCII (i.e. codepoints `00-7F`), but not with extended ASCII, since it uses bytes `80-FF` to form non-ASCII characters. For example, the ¢ symbol (`U+00A2`) is represented as `C2 A2`. I have never used libxml2, so my best advice is to convert extended ASCII to UTF-8. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Examples) is a link that might help you.